# Requirement is to remove only the addressbar on a browser window but retain the rest of the toolbar options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my project I have a requirement where in I need to remove the addressbar for a pop up but retain the back,forward and refresh buttons on the tool bar. So the option toolbar=0 for the pop up does not work for me. I just want to remove the addressbar and nothing else from the browser pop up. Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `location=0` in the option string (see the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) and [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs), but do note that most modern browsers will force the presence of the location bar anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you testing in? Someone else chime in if I am wrong but I think Chrome will not let you remove the address bar.